# How to create 2D from 1D array with loop and manipulation?

Tags: php, arrays

How to create a 2-dimensional from a 1-dimensional array in PHP?
For example I have one array as :

```
$a = Array
        (
            [0] => qwer
            [1] => asdfg
        )
```

And I want to convert it to be like this :

```
$b = Array
    (
        [0] => array
               (
                  [0] => qw
                  [1] => we
                  [2] => er
               )
        [1] => array 
              (
                  [0] => as
                  [1] => sd
                  [2] => df
                  [3] => fg
              )
    )
```

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substr`, loop the `$a` array and store it in `$b` array.

**CODE:**

```
$a = array(
        0 => 'qwer',
        1 => 'asdfg'
    );

$b = array();
$a_length = count($a);
for($i = 0; $i < $a_length; $i++){
    // Create new array
    $b[$i] = array();
    // Get the string length of $a element and minus it to 1
    for($j = 0; $j < (strlen($a[$i]) - 1); $j++){
        // Add it to our new array.
        $b[$i][] = substr($a[$i], $j, 2);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => qw
            [1] => we
            [2] => er
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => as
            [1] => sd
            [2] => df
            [3] => fg
        )

)
```

Comment: While this does indeed provide the solution, I'd disagree that there's "*Nothing much to explain here*". You could, for instance, simply assign `$b` to the desired output and achieve the same result. A few sentences covering exactly how this approach achieves the desired output and why it will work for all instances would really help the OP's knowledge :)